# Is blob datatype in sql same as blob in spring

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, blob

I'm having a service which accepts post request and get the data in the body and save it in a MySQL DB. I'm having a blob data type in MySQL, and I am trying to save such data in spring Blob data type. Is this the right way or not?

EDIT:  I am using hibernate to store data in mysql

Comment: are both blobs in sql and spring are same, i mean used for same purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring JdbcTemplate, then it works fine with Blob type in JDBC. Here is an example:

DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE  `imgs` (
  `img_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `img_title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `img_data` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`img_id`)
);
```

Java code:

```
public interface ImageDao {
 public void insertImage();
}

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Types;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.SqlLobValue;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.LobHandler;

public class ImageDaoImpl implements ImageDao {

 private DataSource dataSource;

 private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

 public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
  this.dataSource = dataSource;
  this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
 }

 @Override
 public void insertImage() {

  try {
   final File image = new File("C:\\test.jpg");
   final InputStream imageIs = new FileInputStream(image);   
   LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler(); 
   jdbcTemplate.update(
         "INSERT INTO imgs (img_title, img_data) VALUES (?, ?)",
         new Object[] {
           "test",
           new SqlLobValue(imageIs, (int)image.length(), lobHandler),
         },
         new int[] {Types.VARCHAR, Types.BLOB});


  } catch (DataAccessException e) {
   System.out.println("DataAccessException " + e.getMessage());
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   System.out.println("DataAccessException " + e.getMessage());
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: i am using hibernate will it also work for same data type

Comment: @Labeo I guess so. Hibernate is built on top of JDBC. So it makes no sense to create its own Blob type rather than reuse JDBC's.

Comment: so both blobs in sql and spring are same  i mean used for same purpose

Comment: @Labeo Yep, you got it.